# Export SQL results to separate files

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In order to have test samples, I would like to export each line of a request result to a separate files.

SQL Developper displays a "Save As : Separate Files" option in "Export" menu but whatever the chosen format, it always export to a single file.

Any idea how to export to multiple files ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use SQL Developer? Or could you also use SQL/Plus?

Comment: I could also use SQL Plus, if there is a way to export lines in separate files, but I do not know well this tool.

Comment: unfortunately, it appears from reading the help documentation that when they separate files, they mean separate files for the different "objects" like table definitions, records, etc

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to export as the single file, and use csplit on line breaks:

```
csplit export.tsv '/\n/' {1}
```